# pointer and multidimensional array

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

i want to print the value which contain in the multidimensional array.I know that if we write something like `arr[3][4]` then `arr[0]` is the pointer to the first element in the that multidimensional array.
I want to ask why this code give me garbage value after the program print the number containing in the multidimensional array?

this is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define ROW 3
    #define COLL 4

    int main(void) {
    int arr[ROW][COLL]={{1,2,3,4},
                  {5,6,7,8},
                  {9,10,11,12}};
    int *ptr;

    for(ptr=arr[0];ptr<arr[ROW]+COLL;ptr++){
        printf("%d ",*ptr);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

this is the result when i compile the above code:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 -1079481492 134513936 0 -1079481352
```

but after changing the for loop to the following:

```
for(ptr=arr[0];ptr<=arr[ROW-1]+COLL-1;ptr++)
```

the code work and give the exact number which contain in the multidimensional array.

Comment: array access row from `0..1..and 2` and here you want to access `3` means fourth raw's first element which is not there. So it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: `for(ptr=&arr[0][0];ptr<&arr[ROW-1][COLL];ptr++){`

Answer (score 2):

Because `arr[ROW]` is an out-of-bounds access. The last valid position in `arr` is `arr[ROW-1]`. Thus the first version of your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: what is out-of-bound acces?
can you explain that?

Comment: @harianja: He means that you're trying to access something past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer to the last element is

```
arr[ROW-1] + COLL - 1
```

So you loop should be

```
    for (ptr = arr; ptr < arr[ROW-1] + COLL; ptr++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements of an array are indexed from 0 so the last element in your matrix is `arr[ROW-1][COLL-1]`.

When your pointer reaches `arr[2] + COLL` there is no such element because the second coordinate of the last element in last row is `[COLL-1]`.

Elements of an array are stored in 1D so `arr[0] + 4` is acctualy `arr[1][0]`.
When you increment `ptr++` it tells the compiler to access the next memory location after the current. So, when `ptr` points to `a[0] + 4` it works because the compiler access the fifth value after `a[0][0]` which is actually the first value in the next row, `arr[1][0]`, because their memory locations are next to each other.

When your `ptr` points to `arr[4] + i, i = 0, 1, 2, 3` you get bad output because those elements are not in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Because your first element, 1, is at `arr[0]+0`,

5 is at `arr[1]+0`,

9 is at `arr[2]+0`,

10 is at `arr[2]+1`,

11 is at `arr[2]+2`,

and 12, which is the last element of your array is at `arr[2]+3`.

but your for loop keeps moving even after the array ends, that is, until the memory location arr[3]+4 is reached. Giving you four garbage values because we have stored nothing in the memory after arr[2]+3.

so the for loop should be like:

```
for (ptr=arr; ptr <= arr[ROW-1]+COLL-1; ptr++);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
for (ptr=arr[0]; ptr <= arr[ROW-1]+COLL-1; ptr++);
```

as arr[0] and arr point to the same location in memory.
NOTE- try reading how memory is allocated in arrays of multiple dimensions.